# Use Case Diagram for Login Module

Tags: uml, diagram, use-case, use-case-diagram

[image: Use Case for Login Module]

I made a simple Use Case for Login module I was working on.

In there I have three types of ways to log in and I was wondering if this is the correct way.

Or is it better if I have a single Login process and the Facebook, Email and Google are extended to it.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: there is no difference between your three primary actors, they activate the same UCs => they are only one, remove inherited actors. Is *SendResetEmail*  can be activated in an other case, if no delete it, UC are not about conception

Comment: @bruno Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing that would be syntactically wrong in your diagram.

Nevertheless a couple of remarks:

- `Check suspended` and `Send reset email` seem to be actions rather than use cases. To be a use case they should at least imply interactions with the actors.
- The user specialisation is not really needed, since the diagram shows no specifics at use-case level. It has the benefit to remind  that there are different kind of users but you may convey this information in another way.
- If you chose to keep it because if the big picture, the actors should correspond to roles in the interactions with the system. If the system is about `volunteers` for assisting `blind and visually impaired people`, who can ask for support, it’s ok. If not, it could appear ambiguous. Because [accessibility requirements](https://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/accessibility.html) should be an implicit requirement for every use-case in every system and should not need explicit actor specialisation in use-case diagrams.

And some advices:

- use-cases should in principle have value for the actors and correspond to some of their goals. It’s meant for keeping a view on the big picture and not to decompose in details how the system shall proceed.  Therefore keep it simple. A single login use-case and eventually a reset password use-case seem more than sufficient.
- in order to promote the big picture,make your secondary actor as general as possible:
  use `Identity provider`. This will help you to design a future proof system with sound separation of concerns: whenever a [new identity provider](https://auth0.com/blog/what-is-sign-in-with-apple-a-new-identity-provider/) appears, you could just implement a new specialization of some classes. without changing your use-case nor fundamentally reviewing your design.